# Getting a list of data based on Items associated with User

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called `reviews`.  I get the most current user reviews like this:

```
SELECT b.item, b.item_id, a.review_id, a.review, c.category, u.username, c.cat_id 
FROM reviews a
INNER JOIN items b
     ON a.item_id = b.item_id
INNER JOIN master_cat c
     ON c.cat_id = b.cat_id
INNER JOIN users AS u
     ON u.user_id = a.user_id               
ORDER BY a.review_id DESC;
```

What I want to do is slightly alter it to be more personable for users.

I have another table of user "connections".  Kind of like Twitter.  When a user follows someone, it gets logged in this table called `profile_follow`. This has three columns.  `id`, `user_id`, `follow_id`.  Simply:  If I am user #1, and I "follow" user # 3  and user #5, two rows will be added in this table:

```
     profile_follow
------------------------
id | user_id | follow_id
   | 1       | 3
   | 1       | 5
```

Here is how I want to change the query above.  I want to only show newest reviews, **from people you follow**.

So I will need at least one more join, for table `profile_follow`.  And I need to pass in a user_id (it's a `php` function), doing something like `WHERE profile_follow.user_id = '{$user_id}'.  I think I will have to add a sub query on this, not use.

*Can someone show me how to finish this query?* I am not sure how to handle it from here?  All of my attempts have been off so far.

I think I need to do something like:

`Select`follow_id`where`user_id`= (logged in user)`

And then in the main query:

`Select reviews only with profile_follow.follow_id = review.user_id.`

I can't figure out how to make this filter work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always difficult without testing, but:

```
SELECT b.item, b.item_id, a.review_id, a.review, c.category, u.username, c.cat_id 
FROM reviews a
INNER JOIN items b
     ON a.item_id = b.item_id
INNER JOIN master_cat c
     ON c.cat_id = b.cat_id
INNER JOIN profile_follow pf
     ON pf.follow_id = a.user_id
WHERE profile_follow.user_id = '{$user_id}'
ORDER BY a.review_id DESC;
```

Comment: Well this is kind of what I did in my testing.  Basically I used my profile as an example to what you suggest.  I am `user_id` #1 following 9 other users.  So using your query above, it took my reviews, and repeated them each 9 times.

Comment: Oops - edited to use follow_id in the final join, that should do.

Comment: hey! perfect, I can't believe it was so simple; I was totally overthinking this!